# Connect with Visual Studio 2012 and C sharp to microsoft cloud TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am building an asp.net **webforms** site that can connect to our tfs hosted on **Microsoft** (http://companyname.visualstudio.com) and get data from it. When I run the project with Cassini it runs fine as it gets the authentication from the browser. But I want to do this from code behind.

I have tried various setups like

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(CollectionUri, new UICredentialsProvider());
```

[which is now deprecated as method and should not be used]

or

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(CollectionUri);
```

or even with

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(CollectionUri, new NetworkCredential("windowsliveid","password"));
```

I have no domain since it is a Windows Liveid

and then

```
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Also I get the uri through

```
var CollectionUri = new Uri("https://companyname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/");
```

Any ideas on how to properly authenticate. I would love to either prompt the auth window or give username and password directly.

------------------------------ SOLVED !!! ---------------------------------

Here is the solution to it after some googling following Martin Woodward's very helpful suggestion.

First alternate credentials have to be activated through the TFS account. Then the code can be changed into this which works fine :)

Just remember that you need to have the latest version of VS 2012 (at least update1) for the code to work. Else you can't reference BasicAuthCredential.

```
        var nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        var bc = new BasicAuthCredential(nc);
        var tfsc = new TfsClientCredentials(bc) {AllowInteractive = false};
        var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(CollectionUri, tfsc);
        tfs.Authenticate();
```

And here are the referenced dlls.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [service credentials](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-service-credential-viewer/), or try enabling alternate credentials on your account which will then allow you to authenticate using http basic auth.

You probably want service credentials for what it sounds like you are doing though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great suggestion. It helped my find a solution eventually!!!